# Robot oscillating before stopping if an obstacle found in ros navigation setup

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My robot is oscillating before stopping if an obstacle is found in the path. This is because, when the robot sees an obstacle, the planner still plan a path through the narrow gap around the obstacle through which the robot can not actually navigate. So how to make the planner not plan a path if the passage if very narrow and the controller should stop the robot. How to solve this problem in ROS navigation stack.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301603/robot-oscillating-before-stopping-if-an-obstacle-found--in-ros-navigation-setup/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2018-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would certainly help to have more information about your robot, and your move_base configuration -- but generally I would say: if the global planner is coming up with a path that the local_planner cannot actually follow (which is what it sounds like), you need to revisit your parameters.

I'd suggest looking closely at the robot inflation in both the global and local costmap -- they should probably be the same, or at least the global should probably be bigger than the local_costmap (since the global planner doesn't really take into account your base drive kinematics).

This [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide) has more about tuning the navigation stack.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2018-08-27**:
Welcome back @fergs! :)

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2018-08-27**:
Thanks Martin!

**Comment by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on 2018-08-28**:
I already added footprint of the robot in costmap_common_parameter file. I also added inflation radius in this file. So both  local_costmap  and  global_costmap will use this information. Then why stiil the robot robot oscillation before stopping if it sees an obstacle in the path way.